# After 4 days app is still not indexed in Google Play search

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application

I have published my first application (Voice To SMS) on google play 4 days ago and I still can't find my app in search by it's name or developer name. I can find my app only by package name or by real app name but without spaces - "VoiceToSMS".

Link to my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SpeechProcessing.Voice.To.SMS.Converter&hl=en

As we can see, in the bottom of the page there is no even "Similar apps" section...

In Google Play developer console everything seems OK (except that my app is not designed for tablets). 0 errors, I selected all available countries for distribution, app status is "Published". In app description I wrote some keywords.

What could be wrong? Maybe app is not indexed because its name is not specific?

I am attaching manifest.xml additionally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.SpeechProcessing.Voice.To.SMS.Converter"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"  >

     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.SpeechProcessing.Voice.To.SMS.Converter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges=
"keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Google Play is a large store your app is indexed however its more of a first come first serve and highest ratings or unique search terms on Google play you will probably find you app on the last page, hopefully it will work its way up or try: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%22Voice%20To%20SMS%22&c=apps

Comment: Keep patience, the market is full of similar apps. So it will take a while to reach that status.

Comment: I can't find my app even in the last page. By the way, I saw some apps which has less downloads, doesn't have any rates and recommendations in google+ but it's possible to find them normally by name.

Comment: Hope it's really problem just because of huge traffic in google servers...

Answer (score 2):

Well, more  than 2 weeks gone after uploading my app on Google Play. My app is finally searchable by term "voice to sms". In my strong opinion, it wasn't Google-side issue that app wasn't searchable for a while by mentioned term.

I did one SEO trick - in app description I included some keywords whose are popular but not so like "voice to sms". In result, I got more downloads and growing my app's search rank. After few days, my app's rank was enough high that Google could show my app in results of "voice to sms" search term.

So, if you have similar problems - focus on SEO for your app.

Comment: I'm in your situation. 4 days after publishing and still no indexing. App is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.omnys.tapthecolor  Did your app became searchable right after your description edit?

Comment: No, few days later as I remember. Currently I can find your app by the full name - "Tap the color (not the word!)". But if I type only "Tap the color" - I can't find your app.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. My app is still outside the standard 250 apps that shows in search!! Infact, if I search for the app name between quotes, it shows up. Now I have to understand what make apps increase their search rank. My app has more downloads and ratings than many others that show up in search. Were you able to understand this?