# Google Play: application is not visible with search keyword

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have uploaded an application in Google play. Application is available region specific. Application is uploaded in production with full-roll out.

In one of the device, application is visible and user installed it. After some X duration, same user in same device when he searches the application, application is not visible.

It's a strange behavior but why this behavior is seen?

Above scenario is searched in device Google play application only.

Comment: post your application name and package name.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal this is an enterprise application,Not authorized to reveal specific details.

Comment: can you ask user to hit using direct link? Does app get listed? When was app published ( please note it takes some time before app is searchable to all users ). It's staged rollout so might take time sometimes depending upon which server your are hitting to search result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might not always show if your app doesn't have enough *unique keywords* in the name. As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17354308/5832311), you can change your name in the Play Store Console and try some different combinations of words.

Also, there's possibility that your app that you're trying to search is not compatible with the device. This might be a reason why it is not showing up in your device. If you will sign into your Google account, then you click the install button (on the desktop site) it will show you the devices that are associated with that account asking with their compatibility. [[Source.]](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-find-the-app-when-searching-by-its-name-in-Google-Play-Store-though-it-is-listed)

You can also check these related SO posts:

- [Google Play is not showing my app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358487/5832311)

> It took almost couple of days for my app to show up. Just a small note, if you cannot find your app in the play store, try putting the name in double quotes like "Park The Car" or "Relationship Guru" and then search it. Even when Play store started showing my app, if I just search with the app name with no double quotes, I could not find it. I saw almost 500 apps and still I could not find my app. But on using double quotes, I got a perfect string match.

- [After 4 days app is still not indexed in Google Play search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022211/after-4-days-app-is-still-not-indexed-in-google-play-search)

Hope this helps!

Comment: " try putting the name in double quotes like "Park The Car" or "Relationship Guru" and then search it."- yes this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Each time you release an app, the search ranking in the play store will be temporarily hit.
However, it will be restored within a day or two.
If your search visibility went out of ranking soon after the new update got to live in the play store, then there is nothing to worry about. It will be back soon.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play search is a key tool for users to find relevant, and popular apps for Android devices. Ensuring that your app and store listing are thorough and optimized is an important factor in getting discovered by users on Google Play and you can optimize your search by following the steps in the following official link by Google.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en